# Why does the field in my recursive Java method change?

Tags: java, recursion, pass-by-reference

I have been learning Java for about a month now and have learned a lot by reading others' questions (and answers) on this site.  I don't think that this has been asked before (but if it has, I would appreciate a pointer ...)

In the code below, pretty much everything which is not indented are error-checking printouts, so the code is quite a bit shorter than it seems.  The code is my attempt at using recursion to list all the ways that `numBalls` balls can be placed in `numBins` bins.

Main question: The method works fine for `numBins` < 3.  As soon as `numBins` is set to 3, the `endList` field (in the recursive call) has more than 1 "row", and as soon as j hits 1 in the loop directly below, the `indexList` field gets changed.  For example, `calling testList = distributeBallsInBins(1,3,"");` in the main method (as it is configured), leads to a change in the second row of `indexList` from {0 1 0} to {0 0 1} (as shown in the output) , but I cannot see how/why it has changed when all I have done is moved to the next j (i.e. from j=0 to j=1)

Secondary question: I have replaced all the `Integer[]` occurrences with `int[]` and there seems to be no difference.  Should there be?  I guess I need to read more on the difference between primitive and reference types, but I don't really understand the difference here.

Thank you in advance,
Mike

```
import java.util.*;

public class testRecursion
{
     public static List<Integer[]> distributeBallsInBins(int numBalls, int numBins, String tmpTxt)
    {
        if (numBins==1)
        {
            List<Integer[]> lastList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
            lastList.add((new Integer[] {numBalls}));
            return lastList;
        }
        else if (numBalls==0)
        {
            List<Integer[]> lastList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
            Integer[] tmpNum = new Integer[numBins];
            for (int k=0; k<numBins; k++)
                tmpNum[k] = 0;
            lastList.add(tmpNum);
            return lastList;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Integer[]> indexList = new ArrayList<Integer[]>();
            for (int i=numBalls; i>=0; i--)
            {
                Integer[] newLine = new Integer[numBins];
                newLine[0] = i;
                List<Integer[]> endList = distributeBallsInBins((numBalls-i), (numBins-1), (tmpTxt + "    "));
                for (int j=0; j<endList.size(); j++)
                {
                    Integer[] newLineEnd = endList.get(j);
                    for (int k=0; k<numBins-1; k++)
                        newLine[k+1] = newLineEnd[k]; 
                    indexList.add(newLine);
                }
            }
        return indexList;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<Integer[]> testList = distributeBallsInBins(1,3,"");
    }
}
```

Comment: Let us make the world a better place to live in - Indent your code.

Comment: Please use spaces rather than tabs to indent your code - tabs don't work terribly well in Stack Overflow.

Comment: I did indent (everything but the error-checking, which I don't so that I can take it out easily), but used tabs - I have edited it to clean this up.  Thanks for the hint

Comment: I included error-printing code to show where I think the problem is.  I thought it would help me explain what I have done.  I have removed it at your suggestion.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is, that you are always modifying and inserting the same array into your result list. Since `Java` handles all objects per reference, you'll end up with a list containing the same array over and over again.

So you need to either `clone` the array before adding it to the list:

```
indexList.add(newLine.clone());
```

Or create the `newLine` array new every time you iterate your `j`-loop:

```
for (int j = 0; j < endList.size(); j++) {
    Integer[] newLine = new Integer[numBins];
    newLine[0] = i;
    Integer[] newLineEnd = endList.get(j);
    for (int k = 0; k < numBins - 1; k++)
        newLine[k + 1] = newLineEnd[k];
    indexList.add(newLine);
} // next j
```

Regarding Objects versus primitives: Changing to `int[]` did not help because the `array` itself is still an `Object` and thus passed by reference.

Comment: Michael, thanks.  I will have to read up on clones, but the second fix worked great.  I tried so many things, but not that (thought the way I had it was more efficient - not having to set the newLine[0] value every time).  I guess I need to understand referencing better.

Comment: Michael, regarding the int[] versus Integer[], I did not expect that to solve the problem, just was somewhat surprised that it made no difference (in this program, at least).  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

just replace this line

```
indexList.add(newLine);
```

with Line

```
indexList.add(newLine.clone());
```

this will work......
this will pass new array rather than pass the reference of old array.......